# FILTER() problems with integrity with other columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

It's my first post here and I need some help in Google Sheets. I am trying to filter() data dynamically and then sort them but here's the thing. I get the first column (D) with filter() function, the rest was output straight into columns E and F.

```
=FILTER('TEST'!A:A;'TEST'!J:J="I")
```

But I need to sort them later on and remain the rows consistent with other data which are TRUE and FALSE.
The problem is that when someone adds a value in the center of the the filtered data, TRUE and FALSE values do not "drop" down with their "parent".

### Data Before:

[image: Data before]

### Data After:

[image: Data after]

### Data I Need:

[image: Data I need]

Comment: Hello @RafałMeler, so you are trying to sort the *results of the filters functions* based on their `TRUE` or `FALSE` values? Cheers!

Comment: That's the tricky part. I want to sort the results of the FILTER() function, but I also want to maintain the 'relation' in row between columns if a new value in D column appears. It's hard for me to describe it. The D column is entirely made by filter() function, but the visible TRUE and FALSE values were placed manually by the user and need to be moved automatically with column D index when sorting.

Comment: Why is E9:F9 empty in **Data I need**?

Comment: Rolled back because it was unclear what each of the three screenshots meant.

Comment: @TheMaster FILTER4 is the added value which is shown by `FILTER()` function. I wanted to represent that FILTER4 should have its own row and FILTER3 takes the whole row down

Comment: Step back and Rework your original problem that led to this solution(Like, putting the checkbox in the source sheet `TEST`). As it is, you would need a complicated script to achieve what you're trying to achieve( which if you want to do,, you must at least know basic scripting).

Comment: Hello @RafałMeler, would you mind rephrasing your question and providing more useful/helpful examples that can help us diagnose your issue accordingly? That would be of great help! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you could use script for extended range:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");                   // SHEET NAME HERE
var range = sheet.getRange("D7:F");                        // RANGE TO BE SORTED

function onEdit(e)  {                                      // COLUMN NUMBER AND SORTING
range.sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}, 
            {column: 2, ascending: false}]);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I need to link these true and false values to filtered indexes somehow.

Comment: FILTER1, FILTER2, FILTER 3, FILTER4 are the values returned by FILTER() function

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sure [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EIgO28BvQnXZRIrIuBWOBGjgcfjiRPKmvLEAvRyrfYA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: JavaScript boolean types are `true` and `false`. There is no ``TRUE`` and `FALSE`(Note the case)

Comment: @TheMaster uhm... it's about the `TRUE` and `FALSE` output in a spreadsheet not javascript...